# Getting TOP 10 records from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sorting, integer

recently I've made some research and did not found anything that could be helpfull.

I'm looking for way to get TOP 10 integers from MySQL.

Here's the look of my database:
http://screenshooter.net/100248235/ktpnmch

I need to get 10 highest records from this base sorted by `pkt` value. From highest to lowest.

Next thing i need to do is create a loop and display it in console. Just like:

## 1 - Ethrisable: 100pkt, 1zab, 2smr

## 2 - Mada5: 98pkt, 10 zab, 500smr

.
.
.

Hope u can give me some advices, 'cuz im just starting to get used to MySQL.

Comment: You need the top 10 rows from a table consisting of 6 rows. It's going to be a long day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LIMIT keyword to restrict the number of records returned:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY pkt DESC LIMIT 10
```

More details at:  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: I might be wrong, but this code does not sort records in order, does it?

Comment: Ahh.. you need sorting too?  I'll adjust

Comment: Oh, that's all? I though it have to be more complicated :> I will try it out. Thank you.

Comment: My last question: The result is from lowest to highest. How to sort it reverse way?

Comment: The ORDER BY clause has a DESC argument to indicate sort DESCENDING.  You can also use the ASC keyword to sort ASCENDING.  I am using uppercase for the SQL keywords to make it more readable, and this is not required

Answer (score -1):

Please use this my mysql query and write a `table name` in text remove and edit your table name.

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT MAX(pkt) AS pkt,Nazwa,Zab,smr 
    FROM `table name`
    LIMIT 0 , 10
    ");
```

Comment: This is using an aggregate MAX clause with no grouping. That will return 1 result row with the highest number in the pkt column